# Find Regular Grammar from NFA

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm currently doing some self study to improve my half-forgotten college theory of comp skills.

I'm going over some problems from an old book and it asks you to find a regular grammar for the pictured NFA. The language of the NFA is a+b+  , but I do not know the steps in finding the regular grammar. I understand regular grammar when presented to me, but find it hard to place together all the possible scenarios without forgetting some.

For example, I started and came up with:

```
S -> aAb | aBb | ab
A -> aA | a
B -> bB | b
```

I know its not correct but i'm stuck on how to start building the grammar from scratch. Can anyone help define some steps to take to solve the problem?

Comment: Is this a mathematics question?

Comment: @Sergio: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar should simply produce a string of one or more $a$’s followed by a string of one or more $b$’s. One set of productions that will do this is:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aS\mid aB\\
&B\to bB\mid b
\end{align*}$$

Here $S$ is the initial symbol. We can begin by applying the production $S\to aS$ any non-negative number of times, but eventually we must apply $S\to aB$ if we’re to generate a terminal string. If we applied $S\to aA$ $n$ times, at that point we have $a^{n+1}B$. We can then apply $B\to bB$ any non-negative number of times, but eventually we must apply $B\to b$ to complete the derivation of a terminal string. If we applied $B\to bB$ $m$ times, we end up with $a^{n+1}b^{m+1}$. Since $n$ and $m$ are any non-negative integers, we can generate all words of the form $a^kb^\ell$ with $k,\ell\ge 1$, and those are precisely the words described by the regular expression $a^+b^+$.